# Enforce all child classes to contain variables of only a certain type

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Here are my classes:

```
   public abstract class Input
{

}

public class CreatePendingOrderInput : Input
{
    public string customerNo;
    public string callingCountry;
}

public class GetCustomerDetailsInput : Input
{
    public string customerName;
    public string customerAge;
}
```

I want to enforce that any class that is a child of `Input` only define variables of type `string`. Is this possible?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: You could use reflection, but that would only be enforced at runtime. The only way to enforce this at compile time would be with an extension in Visual Studio which you'd have to create.

Comment: This is [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295), why do you want such enforcement? Maybe you simply need `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's impossible. 
The only thing that is enforced when deriving from a base class is that the derived class has everything the base class have, except for constructors and finalizers.